# Double ternary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was going through some stuff in the jQuery source, specifically the `inArray` method and I found this line of code:

```
i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;
```

What I am seeing is two ternary operators, but I have no idea how this is used.  I understand how the ternary operator works, but I have never seen it used like this before. How does this piece of code work??

Comment: Exactly how you'd expect; break it down.

Comment: how bout: i = i ? ((i < 0) ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i) : 0;

Comment: People who write code like this without parentheses.. ugh

Comment: or people who write code like this.... show off, but doing it incorrectly.

Comment: It is also mentioned as a bad example in The Modern JavaScript Tutorial:
https://javascript.info/ninja-code#brevity-is-the-soul-of-wit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just break it down like you would `1 + 2 + 3`:

```
if (i) {
    if (i < 0) {
        i = Math.max(0, len + i);
    } else {
       i = i; // no-op
    }
} else {
    i = 0; // also no-op, since if `i` were anything else it would be truthy.
}
```

In fact, that whole line seems inefficient to me. Personally I'd just use:

```
if (i < 0) { 
    i = Math.max(0, len + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  Why do we do the `Math.max(0, len+1)`?  I realize it's to find the biggest value, but why does this happen??

Comment: What does no-op stand for?

Comment: No operation.  Nothing happens to the value.

Comment: it's Math.max(i,len+i).  that is an i not a 1.

Comment: @SethenMaleno  I see what your saying about the inefficiencies, I'm assuming the ternary operator requires both a true and false condition, which is why they have to specify some of the no-op peices

Comment: The original ternary statement handles the case where `i` is undefined or false and sets it to `0`. I think you'd be missing that in your shortened version.

Answer (score 11):

`i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;`

Breaks down to:

```
var i;

if(i){
  if(i<0){
   i = Math.max(0, len + i);
  }else{
    i = i;
  }
}else{
  i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;
```

reads to

```
i = i ? ( i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i ) : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

By any chance, is "i" an index into an array and "len" the length of the array?

If it is so, then that line would do the following:

- if i can be equated to false, then assume it's 0
- else if i is positive or 0, then take it as it is
- else if i is negative, then consider it an index counting from the end of the array (ie. if i==-1, it means the last element of the array).